# Как я могу получить текст ValidationError при обработке формы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, формы

есть код:

```py
class CinemaAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cinema
        fields = ('title', 'adress')
        widgets = {
            'Название': forms.CharField(max_length=30),
            'Адрес': forms.CharField(max_length=250)
        }

    def clean_title(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if data == '':
            # self.add_error('title', "Вы забыли про название кинотеатра")
            raise forms.ValidationError("Вы забыли про название кинотеатра")
        return data

    def clean_adress(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['adress']
        if data == '':
            #self.add_error('adress', "Вы забыли про адрес кинотеатра")
            raise forms.ValidationError("Вы забыли про адрес кинотеатра")
        return data
```

Если какое-то из полей пустое, я хочу при проверке формы вызвать ошибку с текстом, например `Вы забыли про название кинотеатра`, теперь у меня есть `View`:

```py
class AddCinemaApiView(View):
    def post(self, request: WSGIRequest):
        error = ''
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        adress = request.POST.get('adress')
        form = CinemaAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({'ok': True})
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return JsonResponse({'ok': False, 'error': form.errors})
```

Я отправляю в ответ json (данный view вызывается по нажатию кнопки, а через JS fetch делается запрос со всем нужными данными)

И на сайте я хочу вывести ошибки через JS скрипт: [image]

И вроде бы всё должно работать, но почему-то я получаю вот такой текст:
[image]

Хотя ни в одном месте в коде я данный текст не добавлял, соответственно у меня вопрос: как мне получить именно тот текст, который я передаю в ValidationError?

Comment: Покажите вывод `print(form.errors)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил сам:
Модель даёт форме некоторые правила, которые проверяются перед вызовами `clean` для всех полей и всей формы. Если на этом этапе появилась ошибка, то до валидации определенной в форме дело так и не дойдет.

Чтобы избежать этого, в модели нужно указать `blank=false` у нужных полей т.к. именно этот параметр отвечает за возможность оставлять в поле формы пустой текст (не путайте `blank=false` с `null=false`):

> `Field.blank`
>
> Если значение равно `True` , поле может быть пустым. `По умолчанию это False`.
>
> Обратите внимание, что это отличается от null. null относится исключительно к базе данных, а blank относится к валидации. Когда поле есть blank=True , проверка формы позволяет вводить пустые значения. Если в поле есть blank=False , поле необходимо заполнить.

однако, если вы не хотите менять модель (например если форма для пользователя должна работать как-то по своему, а форма в админке - по своему) Вы можете сделать как я: добавить конструктор в форму, и отдельно для каждого поля (или как я, для всех полей), задать

`fields['название поля'].required = False`

Тогда форма не будет следовать правилам определенным в модели, и вы сможете делать валидацию полностью самостоятельно. Вот полный код формы:

```py
class CinemaAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cinema
        fields = ('title', 'adress')

    widgets = {
        'Название': forms.CharField(max_length=30),
        'Адрес': forms.CharField(max_length=250, )
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CinemaAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = False

    def clean_title(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['title'] == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Вы забыли про название кинотеатра")
        return self.cleaned_data['title']

    def clean_adress(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['adress'] == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Вы забыли указать адрес")
        return self.cleaned_data['adress']
```

Answer (score 0):

ты можешь переопределить текст для стандартных сообщений об ошибке у нужных тебе полей

```
class CinemaAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Вы забыли про название кинотеатра'})
    adress = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Вы забыли про адрес кинотеатра'})

    class Meta:
        model = Cinema
        fields = ('title', 'adress')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages